# snowsql connection error happend "250001 n/a"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use snowflake and snowsight on windows OS. And, I did the below command but the error happened.
Do you have the answer about this error 250001 (n/a)?

```
C:\Docs>snowsql -a lvXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.aws -u username -o log_level=DEBUG
Password:
250001 (n/a): Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy in between?

Comment: Did you do what the error message asked you to do?  If so, what did the log file say?

Comment: I thought the error log was output on the prompt, but I see it is output to the logfile.
the error log says "Hit non-retryable SSL error, HTTPSConnectionPool" "Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url:***". So, I check the my network settings. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message appears to be an issue with "Failed to check OCSP response cache file."

You can try to connect using insecure mode to bypass the OCSP checks.

Use this:

```
snowsql -a lvXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.aws -u username -o insecure_mode=True
```

If the connection is successful, it means there may be a firewall/proxy that is blocking the connection to the OCSP server. Note: OCSP connects via port 80.

Comment: I found this is caused by my company's security service which overwrites the server certificate. Thank you for answering.

Comment: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Error-SSL-Certificate-is-invalid-for-URL-The-certificate-chain-is-as-follows

Answer (score 1):

I got this resolved by going in the cd ~/.snowsql/config and changing the accountname =(orgname)-(accountname). Make sure to enter your own orgname and accountname as found in the snowsight UI. And if you copy account name from snowsight UI remove "." from orgname.accountname to orgname-accountname. Alternatively, you can use snowsql -a (orgname)-(accountname) -u (username)

Answer (score 0):

My connection problem was the string. If you include 'https', 'snowflakecomputig.com', etc, the connection won't work for dbt profiles.yml files. You only have to put your account id and region as is illustrated above.